# Would vsftpd not default to using the system username and password?

Tags: linux, configuration, authentication, vsftpd

I downloaded `vsftpd-3.0.5.tar.gz` and successfully compiled it to generate `vsftpd` on computer **A**. Then I copied vsftpd to another computer **B** and created a new file called `vsftpd.conf` on computer A. Then, I started `vsftpd` and could hear the service start through the command `netstat -tulnp | grep 21`. However, at this point, I was unable to access `vsftpd` and prompted the following error. Would vstftpd not default to using the system username and password?Must a new username and password be added?

--

I see that vsftpd distinguishes between `anonymous users`, `local users`, and `virtual users`. I think my problem should be that I want to log in with a `local user` login name on another computer **C**, is that not feasible? Is it just a problem with my `vstftpd.conf` configuration?

error:

```
C:\Users\guoya>ftp 192.168.5.2
连接到 192.168.5.2。
500 OOPS: cannot locate user entry:nobody
远程主机关闭连接。
```

cat /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=No
anon_world_readable_only=NO

listen=YES

write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
local_root=/home/tftpShare
local_umask=022

chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
```

start vsftpd:

```
# ./vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

netstat -tulnp | grep 21

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      553/vsftpd
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been superficially solved by me, but I am still confused. I just want to log in with the username `root` or other newly added username. Why do I have to execute `adduser nobody` before adding a new username?

```
# adduser nobody
Changing password for nobody
New password:
Bad password: too weak
Retype password:
passwd: password for nobody changed by root
```